# How is insert O(log(n)) in Data.Set?

Tags: haskell, complexity-theory, referential-transparency

When looking through the docs of `Data.Set`, I saw that [insertion of an element into the tree is mentioned to be O(log(n))](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html#v%3ainsert). However, I would intuitively expect it to be O(n*log(n)) (or maybe O(n)?), as referential transparency requires creating a full copy of the previous tree in O(n).

I understand that for example `(:)` can be made O(1) instead of O(n), as here the full list doesn't have to be copied; the new list can be optimized by the compiler to be the first element plus a pointer to the old list (note that this is a compiler - not a language level - optimization). However, inserting a value into a `Data.Set` involves rebalancing that looks quite complex to me, to the point where I doubt that there's something similar to the list optimization. I tried reading [the paper that is referenced by the Set docs](http://www.swiss.ai.mit.edu/~adams/BB/), but couldn't answer my question with it.

So: how can inserting an element into a binary tree be O(log(n)) in a (purely) functional language?

Comment: It doesn't need to copy the entire tree - it only need to copy the nodes from the root to the location of the inserted node. There will be log(n) of these in a balanced binary tree.

Comment: The balancing function, for reference, is here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Set-Base.html#balanceL – notice the docs above it have a simpler version listed.

Comment: `(:)` is O(1) by definition --- despite the funny name, it is merely a simple constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no need to make a full copy of a `Set` in order to insert an element into it. Internally, element are stored in a tree, which means that you only need to create new nodes along the path of the insertion. Untouched nodes can be shared between the pre-insertion and post-insertion version of the `Set`. And as [Deitrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165989/how-is-insert-ologn-in-data-set/14166061#comment19626794_14166061) pointed out, in a balanced tree `O(log(n))` is the length of the path of the insertion. (Sorry for omitting that important fact.)

Say your `Tree` type looks like this:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Leaf
```

... and say you have a `Tree` that looks like this

```
let t = Node 10 tl (Node 15 Leaf tr')
```

... where `tl` and `tr'` are some named subtrees. Now say you want to insert `12` into this tree. Well, that's going to look something like this:

```
let t' = Node 10 tl (Node 15 (Node 12 Leaf Leaf) tr')
```

The subtrees `tl` and `tr'` are shared between `t` and `t'`, and you only had to construct 3 new `Nodes` to do it, even though the size of `t` could be much larger than 3.

---

**EDIT: Rebalancing**

With respect to rebalancing, think about it like this, and note that I claim no rigor here. Say you have an empty tree. Already balanced! Now say you insert an element. Already balanced! Now say you insert *another* element. Well, there's an odd number so you can't do much there.

Here's the tricky part. Say you insert *another* element. This could go two ways: left or right; balanced or unbalanced. In the case that it's unbalanced, you can clearly perform a rotation of the tree to balance it. In the case that it's balanced, already balanced!

What's important to note here is that you're *constantly* rebalancing. It's not like you have a mess of a tree, decided to insert an element, but before you do that, you rebalance, and then leave a mess after you've completed the insertion.

Now say you keep inserting elements. The tree's *gonna* get unbalanced, but not by much. And when that does happen, first off you're correcting that immediately, and secondly, the correction occurs along the path of the insertion, which is `O(log(n))` in a balanced tree. The rotations in the paper you linked to are touching at most three nodes in the tree to perform a rotation. so you're doing `O(3 * log(n))` work when rebalancing. That's still `O(log(n))`.

Comment: And the path of insertion has length O(log N) -- so O(log N) new nodes are created.

Comment: For a more detailed analysis of how a self-balancing binary search trees does insertion and re-balancing in O(log n), one could take a look at the Red-black tree article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). There are other self-balancing binary search trees than red-black trees, but the idea is similar.

Answer (score 7):

To add extra emphasis to what dave4420 said in a comment, there are no compiler optimizations involved in making `(:)` run in constant time. You could implement your own list data type, and run it in a simple non-optimizing Haskell interpreter, and it would still be O(1).

A list is *defined to be* an initial element plus a list (or it's empty in the base case). Here's a definition that's equivalent to native lists:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

So if you've got an element and a list, and you want to build a new list out of them with `Cons`, that's just creating a new data structure directly from the arguments the constructor requires. There is no more need to even *examine* the tail list (let alone copy it), than there is to examine or copy the string when you do something like `Person "Fred"`.

You are simply mistaken when you claim that this is a compiler optimization and not a language level one. This behaviour follows directly from the language level definition of the list data type.

Similarly, for a tree defined to be an item plus two trees (or an empty tree), when you insert an item into a non-empty tree it must either go in the left or right subtree. You'll need to construct a new version of that tree containing the element, which means you'll need to construct a new parent node containing the new subtree. But the *other* subtree doesn't need to be traversed at all; it can be put in the new parent tree as is. In a balanced tree, that's a full *half* of the tree that can be shared.

Applying this reasoning recursively should show you that there's actually no copying of data elements necessary at all; there's just the new parent nodes needed on the path down to the inserted element's final position. Each new node stores 3 things: an item (shared directly with the item reference in the original tree), an unchanged subtree (shared directly with the original tree), and a newly created subtree (which shares almost all of its structure with the original tree). There will be O(log(n)) of those in a balanced tree.